# Setup layer-2 bridging between two Juniper vMX

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos

I tried to setup simple L2 bridging on vMX.2 vMX devices: two VLANs (two bridging domains) per device, and trunk links between both. The end devices, VPCs, attached to access ports on each vMX, were unable to communicate.

Can someone explain this to me?

[image]

The configuration I used is below:

```
ge-0/0/1 {
    description " trunk link vMX1->vMX2 handle traffic of VLANID 400,500";
    unit 0 {
        family bridge {
            interface-mode trunk;
            vlan-id-list [ 400 500 ];
        }
    }
}
ge-0/0/2 {
    description "vMX-1->VLAN BLUE/VLANID 400";
    unit 0 {
        family bridge {
            interface-mode access;
            vlan-id 400;
        }
    }
}
ge-0/0/3 {
    description "vMX-1->VLAN RED /VLANID 500";
    unit 0 {
        family bridge {
            interface-mode access;
            vlan-id 500;
        }
    }
}
irb {
    unit 400 {
        family inet {
            address 172.21.17.254/24;
        }
    }
}


root@vMX-1> show configuration bridge-domains
BLUE {
    domain-type bridge;
    vlan-id 400;
    routing-interface irb.400;
}
RED {
    domain-type bridge;
    vlan-id 500;
}

root@vMX-1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `flexible-vlan-tagging` and `encapsulation flexible-ethernet-services` on the physical interfaces. This works for similar setups I have in production.

Edit: on a vMX this might be confusing. By "physical" interface I mean ge-n/n/n rather than the "logical" ge-n/n/n.0

Comment: Thanks Aziraphale for your suggestion ! I activated RSTP on the trunks interfaces and It's working. I'll also test your suggestion.

Comment: Do you have more than one trunk carrying the VLANs? Otherwise I can't see a loop in the configuration...